# Kerberos auth for Tomcat on machine outside domain

Tags: java, tomcat, kerberos, delegation

Can I use AuthValve configured for Kerberos with Tomcat 8 installed on win machine, which is not included in domain?
I hope I do, cuz why else I need a keytab file generated.
Did everything said in Tomcat Kerberos auth tutorial. But still can not login to server. See NOT_PREAUTH_ERR from DC.

Comment: Add `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` systemvar to see more kerberos debug, also in krb5.conf file add `debug=true` attribute to a section of your configuration. What do `jdk/bin/kinit -k -t keys.keytab HTTP/serviceprincipal.host.com@DOMAIN.COM` command say?

Comment: @Whome thanks, you gave me a direction, but I di only few steps. `kinit -k -t tc8enc.keytab HOST/serviceprincipal.host.com@DOMAIN.COM
New ticket is stored in cache file C:\Users\uname\krb5cc_uname`

Comment: **klist** prints `[1]  Service Principal:  krbtgt/serviceprincipal.host.com@DOMAIN.COM`

Comment: Its what debug from log says `Will use keytab        Ordering keys wrt default_tkt_enctypes list        default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 23.        Commit Succeeded        Found KeyTab        [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout        [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject`

Comment: I even can trace dialog with DC by Wireshark, can see there request and ticket response.

Comment: Related to this KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRE/_FAILED error maybe http://blogs.technet.com/b/makeiteasy/archive/2013/01/14/kdc-err-preauth-required-vs-kdc-err-preauth-failed.aspx

Comment: Well, I just stopped and redo everything carefully from very beginning. Now both parties receives tickets, but then both of them decides to downgrade protocol to NTLM. Through wireshark I see Serv->Client (NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE) and C->S (NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE) at same time.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to parse tickets and understand why don't they cooperate with each-other?